# Can we have any other way to access c++ code in Android instead using JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, latency

I am writing a test application to measure the latency can I have anyway I can access the network data frame's (video/audio) time stamp and tag in application layer ? To make sure I don't add any overhead in it I wanted to avoiding JNI, Or JNI is the option?

suggestion are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably possible, but messy, to write an app in pure c++ and get it to run on a rooted phone. However, JNI is actually very easy with the newest NDK. You have to write a few lines of code to get things working. The overhead on loading the library is fair, but you can measure latency in a function in c++, which should be as fast as native c++. The only latency is added when you return results to java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a application using pure cpp, you can get a demo from [android-ndk](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). There is a project called native-activity under samples folder. It's written with pure cpp.

Comment: I just conformation that we needs it to write in the Java only as we needs to communicate with the other stuff as well